# how to get console output from a remote computer (ssh + python)

Tags: python, linux, authentication, ssh, pexpect

I have googled "python ssh". There is a wonderful module [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect), which can access a remote computer using ssh (with password).

After the remote computer is connected, I can execute other commands. However I cannot get the result in python again.

```
p = pexpect.spawn("ssh user@remote_computer")
print "connecting..."
p.waitnoecho()
p.sendline(my_password)
print "connected"
p.sendline("ps -ef")
p.expect(pexpect.EOF) # this will take very long time
print p.before
```

How to get the result of `ps -ef` in my case?

Comment: hmm? p.before should give the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to investigate [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) which is another SSH library for Python.

Comment: After having tried so many different solutions, I think this library is the best practice for now. I even do not have to configure non-password login to run any script on foreign nodes over LAN.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried an even simpler approach?

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> stdout, stderr = Popen(['ssh', 'user@remote_computer', 'ps -ef'],
...                        stdout=PIPE).communicate()
>>> print(stdout)
```

Granted, this only works because I have `ssh-agent` running preloaded with a private key that the remote host knows about.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Is there an easy way to configure private keys for many clients? I have to check log files of 20 machines every week. This is the motivation of writing a python script.

Comment: Well... you'll just have to append your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on each of the machines. Perhaps, if your working set of machines doesn't change a lot, this will be a one time exercise.

BTW, this is a pretty neat article about setting up SSH Agent and more:
http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html

Answer (score 3):

```
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh user@remote_computer ps -ef")
print "connecting..."
i = child.expect(['user@remote_computer\'s password:'])
child.sendline(user_password)
i = child.expect([' .*']) #or use i = child.expect([pexpect.EOF])
if i == 0:
    print child.after # uncomment when using [' .*'] pattern
    #print child.before # uncomment when using EOF pattern
else:
    print "Unable to capture output"


Hope this help..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to send

```
p.sendline("ps -ef\n")
```

IIRC, the text you send is interpreted verbatim, so the other computer is probably waiting for you to complete the command.